Novella about humans living in an alien zoo/preserve. They are physically different, but all mentally based on the same man from Earth
The story is set a few years after the people woke up--they were all different ages, genders, races, etc., but they all had the same memory. Mentally, they were all the same Jewish man from New York, who had lived a full life and whose last memories were of dying in the hospital as an old man. So the new bodies were particularly jarring for the ones who woke up as little black girls, for example.
I'm not sure if the story every says it explicitly, but it becomes clear that they are living in some kind of zoo or nature preserve. I think they do have 20th century-style houses and things (I remember a mention of them playing a lot of baseball early on). The adult women versions have sex with each other (they don't want to have sex with the adult men because they think it would be too weird), but once a year, the adult men versions visit a neighboring exhibit/habitat with aliens who they have sex with. Since it's been a few years, the people are becoming more mentally differentiated, and I think they discuss whether they might start to procreate eventually. They never meet or learn anything about whoever brought them there.
I think this must have been novella length--longer than a short story, but not a full novel. I probably read this before 2013. Had a "Ray Bradbury" feel, but I have no idea whether he actually wrote it or not. It is not Race Against Time by Piers Anthony.

Asked here as well though with no success so far.

"visit a neighboring exhibit/habitat with aliens who they have sex with": humanoid aliens? Human-looking, even?

I think they were kind of manatee-looking. They were intelligent and could talk.
